# p5 show div as mouse moves

Tags: javascript, p5.js

so I have a div and I want it at first to be covered by a black canvas and then as im moving the mouse clear the black color with shape of an ellipse in order to show the div contents. I just got it working with single pixels but not with the shape of an ellipse. help

```
  <div id="mainContent">
  <div> <img id="mainImage" src="tmpfiles/lpz2.jpg"></div>
  </div>
```

my sketch.js

```
function setup(){
  var canvas = createCanvas(100,100);
  canvas.id("sketch-container")
  canvas.parent("mainContent");
  background(0);

}
function draw(){
  var transparent = color("#1C00ff00")
  var x = mouseX;
  var y = mouseY;
  set(x,y,transparent);
  updatePixels();
}
```

my css

```
/*main content */
#mainContent{
  /* background: #000000; */
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#sketch-container{
position: absolute;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
#mainImage{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of achieving this is to use [blend()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/blend) and [blendMode](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/blendMode); `blendMode(REMOVE)` specifically because it

> removes pixels from B with the alpha strength of A,

Where **B** are the pixels already being displayed (the black background of the canvas) and **A** are the *source pixels* (the shapes drawn)

You can [create](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/creategraphics) a transparent mask layer to draw on and use a color with some alpha value (in your case completely solid) to make the shapes you want; then use the `blend` method with the mask layer as a source and `REMOVE` as the blend mode, like this:

```js
let maskCanvas

function setup(){
  var canvas = createCanvas(100,100);
  canvas.id("sketch-container")
  canvas.parent("mainContent");
  background(0);  
  maskCanvas = createGraphics(100, 100)
}

function draw(){
  maskCanvas.fill('red') // Any color will do
  maskCanvas.ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 5)
  blend(maskCanvas, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 100, 100, REMOVE);
}
```

```css
/*main content */
#mainContent{
  /* background: #000000; */
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#sketch-container{
position: absolute;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
#mainImage{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.min.js"></script>

 <div id="mainContent">
  <div> <img id="mainImage" src="https://picsum.photos/200"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, the thing is it just worked with that specific version of p5. But its great. Thanks, you saved me tons of hours.